# ffmpeg - ffmpeg aws lamnda function error

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, aws-lambda

I am getting error

Execution result: failed(logs)
Details

The area below shows the result returned by your function execution. Learn more about returning results from your function.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: eb7906af-f46d-11e8-ae3b-45487c02a68e Process exited before completing request"
}
```

Summary

```
Code SHA-256
ca50xloHl4xLOSWox2xidHxC1VHyNqwq3kECKraw7/c=
Request ID
eb7906af-f46d-11e8-ae3b-45487c02a68e
Duration
38.73 ms
Billed duration
100 ms
Resources configured
128 MB
Max memory used
19 MB
```

Log output

The section below shows the logging calls in your code. These correspond to a single row within the CloudWatch log group corresponding to this Lambda function. Click here to view the CloudWatch log group.

```
START RequestId: eb7906af-f46d-11e8-ae3b-45487c02a68e Version: $LATEST
2018-11-30T07:02:38.509Z    eb7906af-f46d-11e8-ae3b-45487c02a68e    TypeError: Cannot create property 'stack' on string 'Could not find ffmpeg executable, tried "/var/task/node_modules/@ffmpeg-installer/linux-x64/ffmpeg" and "/var/task/node_modules/@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg/node_modules/@ffmpeg-installer/linux-x64/ffmpeg"'

END RequestId: eb7906af-f46d-11e8-ae3b-45487c02a68e
REPORT RequestId: eb7906af-f46d-11e8-ae3b-45487c02a68e  Duration: 38.73 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 19 MB  
RequestId: eb7906af-f46d-11e8-ae3b-45487c02a68e Process exited before completing request
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a kinda same issue with EC2, try [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg) package.

Install the package

```
npm install --save @ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg
```

In your code, use it as below

```
const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path;
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);
```

Comment: I am using same thing and code uploaded on aws lambda function

Comment: did you restart your node instance?

Comment: How we can do restart node instance and i am uploading code on aws lamda function but till got a same error.locally on my system is working fine